# How do I type a function with input and output objects with the same keys but different value types?

Tags: flowtype

Basically, I have a function that will transform an object into a different object, and it's like a dictionary, but I don't know how to type it.

```
var myFunctions = {
  a: () => something1,
  b: () => something2,
  [...]
}
```

gets transformed into

```
var myObject = {
  a: something1,
  b: something2
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With Flow 0.33+ you can use `$ObjMap`

```
type ExtractCodomain = <V>(v: () => V) => V;
declare function f<O>(o: O): $ObjMap<O, ExtractCodomain>;
```

Comment: Is there an explanation available anywhere - and it does not have to be the Flow context (where this still isn't documented at all)? I have no idea what I'm looking at.

Comment: See https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/flow-mapping-an-object-373d64c44592. `$ObjMap<O, M>` defines an object type with the same keys as an existing type, but with different types for each property. The first parameter (`O`) is an existing object type. The second parameter is a type-level function from the type of a property in the original object type to the type of the same property in the new object type. Just like `Array.prototype.map()` creates a new array by transforming each value in an input array, `$ObjMap` creates a new type by transforming each property type in an input type.

Comment: FYI, this is now documented on https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do this with Flow. The closest you can get is probably this:

```
function<T>(obj: T): ([key: $Keys<T>]: boolean)
```

That function is typed to return an object with the same key as input object, but with boolean-only values (as an example, you can specify another type). Sorry to disappoint, but it's hard to type highly dynamic code with Flow in general.

Note that the `$Keys` feature is undocumented because it's not part of the public API, so its behavior is defined solely by its implementation (in other words, it can change anytime).

If you're interested in the details of Flow's type system, check out the typings that come with flow in its own `/lib` directory, for example https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js – you'll see that some things like `Object.assign` are special-cased, so you might not be able to re-implement such things in your own code.

Also, check out http://sitr.us/2015/05/31/advanced-features-in-flow.html for other "dollar features" such as `$Shape` and `$Diff` – it's partially outdated, but can give some good pointers.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikita gave you the best answer for now. That said, the use-case you talked about is being discussed in the issues on the FlowType repository. It may land soon.

As of right now, if you've got mixed type, I'll just fallback to `any`

```
function<T>(obj: T): ([key: $Keys<T>]: any)
```

This way, at least the key names are validated. I expect within a few more versions of Flow, this problem will get solved.