# Flow types on objects

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've been looking at adding Flow to my javascript project.

In several cases, I do something like this, I have an object.

```
const myObject = {
    x: 12,
    y: "Hello World"
}
```

And I have a general function that does some mapping on the object, keeping the keys but replacing the values.

```
function enfunctionate(someObject) {
   return _.mapValues(myObject, (value) => () => value)
}
```

I'd like the function to return the type `{x: () => number, y: () => string}` Is there a way to make this happen?

Of course, I could type it more generically as `{[key: string]: any}` but I'd lose a lot of the static typing I'd like to gain by using flow.

If I could replace my few cases that do this with code generation or macros that could work, but I don't see a good way to do that with flow.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: As u can see here https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/lodash-node/3.1.0/symbols/_.mapValues `mapValues` accepts `any` and returns a **copy** so you cannot keep it in *type*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I type a function with input and output objects with the same keys but different value types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894181/how-do-i-type-a-function-with-input-and-output-objects-with-the-same-keys-but-di)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best you can get at the moment, while it's safer than `{[key: string]: any}` there's still an `any` involved

```
function enfunctionate<O: Object>(someObject: O): { [key: $Keys<O>]: (...rest: Array<void>) => any } {
   return _.mapValues(someObject, (value) => () => value)
}

const obj = enfunctionate(myObject)

obj.x() // ok
obj.unknown() // error
```

EDIT: starting from v.33 you can use `$ObjMap`

```
function enfunctionate<O>(o: O): $ObjMap<O, <V>(v : V) => () => V> {
  return _.mapValues(o, (value) => () => value)
}
```

Comment: Its not prefect, but its a lot better then what I had, thanks!

Comment: Just added a new implementation (v0.33+)

Comment: awesome! How did you find out about this? Is there documentation somewhere?

Comment: By reading the commit log :) https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/5a05018b01e0eb1537598df6ffe1c57233140be5

Answer (score 0):

Flow is able to infer a lot of things. However, if you want to pin the types, then you have to create the types yourself. You need to create a type for the object you are passing to `enfunctionate` and then specify the type that is returned.

You can type the function with [type alias](https://flowtype.org/docs/type-aliases.html#_). So, you can create a new explicit type for that function.

```
function enfunctionate<X, Y>(x: X): Y {
    return _.mapValues(myObject, (value) => () => value)
}
```

As long as you know the type of X, then you know the type of Y. Type aliasing, generics, and unions should be able to give you flexibility you need.

However, I'm also thinking as long as the type of `mapValues` is specified well (hopefully by someone else) then you can get away with just specifying the type that `enfunctionate` takes and let Flow infer the return type of that function.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't really help me. The functions I'm trying to type exist to eliminate boilerplate, so they don't really help if I have to to define the types. Also, _.mapValues faces the same typing problem enfunctioniate does, so pushing the problem there really doesn't help anything.